# Extruding two sides at 90° angle

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

What would you say is the easiest way of extruding the two faces at the first screen so that the model ends up looking like the second?

[image: Before]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In these situations I like to delete the edge and use F2 add-on for reconstructing the geometry(F2 comes with Blender and just needs to be activated in the Preferences). I have it enabled anyway for modeling and this process is quite pleasant because of the simplicity of it - only pressing <kbd>f</kbd> a few times:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bevel the edge in the middle with 2 segments and profile 0, then move the vertex on the side back in place.

Comment: Very creative way of doing it, but wouldn't that create three n-gons on the opposite side? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: This can be avoided if you dissolve the faces first

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it with the *Push/Pull* addon, demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B62SmzSLKdA), addon [here](https://github.com/capnm/b8ExtrudePull). Other than that I'm not sure there is any easy way to do, so I would do this:

- Enable the *Snap* option (*Vertex* mode).
- Extrude the vertical face until it snaps.
- Remove the doubles.
- Delete the inner face.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take my best guess by saying you should extrude along normals with ALT+E

Edit: this screenshots doesn't make a lot of sense, please try to be more descriptive.

Comment: I'm basically trying to fill in the volume between the two faces. I hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

This is using Blender 2.8 under Windows:
[image]
Select the 'Edge' option in the Snap dropdown, but don't enable snapping. Select the vertical back face as shown. Place the mouse cursor over the edge indicated then press 'E' 'X'. Press the CTRL key which will extrude the face to the front edge and click the left mouse button. Select all with the 'A' key, CTRL 'M' to bring up the Merge menu and merge By Distance.
 Sounds long-winded, but only takes a few seconds.

Comment: On reflection you don't actually need to use the 'X' after 'E' as the extrusion will be in the correct direction anyway. Also the Merge menu is ALT M not CTRL M in 2.8! :^(

Comment: Doesn't this create an interior face, though?

Comment: Very neat, but as Robin say, it does in fact create an interior face.

Comment: True. As Moonboots says in his description, delete the face after merging the doubles. Easy enough to do in wireframe mode.